# React router not getting query params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I'm trying to match *mandatory* url params with react-router v3 (3.2.6) but it seems like it's not getting them. The url is the following:

`de/something?color=red&type=square`

The matching I'm trying to do withing the routing is the following:

`<Route path='de/something?color=:color&type=:type' ... />`

When I log that, it seems it gets the `params` (color and type) but the value is `undefined`. I'm logging directly `ownProps.params` which comes from the router.

I'm unsure why it can see that the params are there but wouldn't see the value for it. What am I defining wrong?

I'm aware that I can get the query params from the location itself but I want to match those query params directly as it is mandatory for this url to have those 2 params. Also a disclaimer that I can't upgrade to router version 4 or 5.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: When I make the params optional with:

`<Route path='de/something(?color=:color&type=:type)' ... />`

I can at least reach the url but color and type *values* are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

On the component which gets rendered for your route - `'de/something?color=:color&type=:type'`

You can get the searchParams as

```
// pass the search params from the location prop provided by react router
// to URLSearchParams constructor

const searchQuery = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);

// use the inbuilt methods to get the value for your searchQuery
const color = searchQuery.get("color");
const type = searchQuery.get('type');
```

Reference

[Get Search Query using URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#examples)

Comment: Yes thanks. Maybe I was not clear enough. The url is not flexible, so I want to force it. At least the color param should always be present. So I need to match the url with react-router exactly. When attempting this `<Route path='de/something?color=:color&type=:type' ... />`, it just can't find this url and color and type are undefined so my guess is that I need to change something.